# Animtion, How to add frames at runtime?

Tags: android, animation

How can we add frames and their time duration at run time. For example, if we had to download some images from server and make them to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public yourClass{
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private long FRAME_RATE = 10;
private ArrayList <Bitmap> sherif; /// this is the array of bitmaps
private ImageView myImageView; //this is the imageview you want to animate
int location = 0;
int numberOfImages = 1000;
private void Animate(){
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  myImageView.setImageBitmap(sherif.get(location));
             }
        });
        location++;
        if(location==numberOfImages )
             timer.cancel();
    }
    }, 0, 60000/FRAME_RATE );
}
```

Comment: @sherif I asked about to add images and duration at run time.

Comment: through this answer is it possible to play several images (like video)

Comment: At a first glance, it's more idiomatic to use a Handler and send delayed messages than pure Timers.